# When to use "is" and "are" if the noun is singular but referring to a group or multiple things?

Tags: grammaticality

I am not sure sure I phrased the question properly. However, consider the following example:

- The roundness of the shapes are strange.
- The roundness of the shapes is strange.

In this scenario, I think "is" is correct because if I remove "of the shapes" the proper word to use is "is". Right? My reasoning is roundness is not plural.

However, using "are" sounds/feels correct instead of using "is". I know "feel" is not necessarily a good method for determining grammar, but this is making me unsure.

Edit: I will add more context.

I chose the word "roundness" for a specific purpose. If the shapes have similar roundness or different roundness, the word "roundness" will still be used. However, if I replace roundness with colors, depending on if I am grouping all the colors together or if I am considering the colors distinctly seems to matter. Consider another example:

1. The colors of the shapes are strange.
2. The color of the shapes are strange. (not correct)
3. The colors of the shapes is strange. (not correct)
4. The color of the shapes is strange.

This correct answer to this case seems more obvious than the previous as we don't have a plural form of roundness. So, what word is proper for the first example? Does the context matter?

Comment: @EddieKal Why is this not suited for this site? I am a native speaker, which is why I am stuck on the "sound" or "feel" of the sentence. I added more context...

Comment: Try what are probably more familiar-sounding sentences. 'The mood of the people is ugly' or 'The mood of the people are ugly'? // 'The colour of the birds was green' or 'The colour of the birds were green'? The prepositional phrase does not affect agreement: The mood **is** ugly // The colour **was** green. // This is not a question suitable for a site aimed at linguists, as Eddie says.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Perhaps, the help center needs updated for this site. According to https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic, the question seems suitable. Also, I am curious about words that have the same singular as plural; thus, the context is only provided in the prepositional phrase.